# Need help to Convert Powershell IE auto login script to firefox having same function

Tags: powershell

I am successfully getting my scenario on below powershell script to auto login to the website xyz.com via IE but some functionality are not working properly, whereas firefox is doing same job perfectly. hence need help to convert the same script to perform same job in firefox browser using powershell.

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible
$username="username"
$password="password"
$Tenant="abcdefgh"
$ie.Navigate("htt:/xyz.com/login") ## website is taken as example
While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}
$usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('txtudsr')
$usernamefield.value = "$username"
$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('txtpswd')
$passwordfield.value = "$password"
$Tenantfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('txttfenant')
$Tenantfield.value = "$Tenant"
$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('btn_login')
$Link.click()
While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 30;}
$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('btn_Continue')
$Link.click()
While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 10;}
$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('statusUnAvailable')
$Link.click()
$ie.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea do the same on firefox as you do for IE.

Your best friend will be `selenium`, it is the modern way to do browser automation nowadays.

I normally use selenium on Python, but there are some articles about selenium on PowerShell too. Just google it.

https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell
https://gist.github.com/Jaykul/d16a390e36ec3ba54cd5e3f760cfb59e

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i will look into it. But if i can get help to have with firefox will be good. Anyway i am looking to run this script for 9 hour window, where this has to execute multiple events during the run.